# Qual logica posso utilizar pra remover uma classe e adicionar a mesma classe removida em outro elemento?

Tags: javascript, html, css

eu gostaria de poder ao clicar nos botoes do menu adicionar a classe estilizada e voltar o estilo normal no botão anterior por exemplo: quando eu clico no botão 1 ele fica com estilo, depois quando clico no botão 2 ele fica com o estilo e o botão 1 perde o estilo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código atual é o seguinte:

```
 let menu = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item');
 menu.forEach((item) =>{

    item.addEventListener('click', function(){   
       item.classList.add('menu-item-actived');   
       
       
    });

 });
```

Comment: item.addEventListener('click', function(el){   
item.classList.remove('menu-item-actived');   
       el.classList.add('menu-item-actived');   
       
       
    });  Tenta isso

Comment: a forma mais fácil seria remover o estilo de todos os botões e em seguida adicionar só ao botão que deve ter o estilo

Comment: Olá Ricardo tudo bem? Poderia me dizer mais sobre como fazer isso?

Comment: hugocsl Obrigado pela dica, vou tentar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blza Filipe? não sei se ja foi solucionado mas vou deixar aqui uma solução simples:

Sempre que um botão é clicado, será verificado se existe algum botão com a classe "menu-item-actived", e a classe será sempre removida antes de adicionar em outro botão.

```js
let menu = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item')

menu.forEach((item) => {

  item.addEventListener('click', function() {

    let botao = document.querySelectorAll('#minha-div .menu-item-actived');

    botao.length != 0 ? botao[0].classList.remove("menu-item-actived") : botao.length;

    item.classList.add('menu-item-actived');

  });

});
```

```css
.menu-item-actived {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="minha-div">
  <input type="button" class="menu-item" value="Botão 1">
  <input type="button" class="menu-item" value="Botão 2">
  <input type="button" class="menu-item" value="Botão 3">
  <input type="button" class="menu-item" value="Botão 4">
</div>
```

Comment: Olá Igor, muito obrigado por sua resposta! Eu tinha resolvido de outra forma (gambiarra), mas vou tentar da sua forma!

Comment: @FilipeGomes a solução do Igor Bezerra serviu pra você?

Comment: @Cmte Cardeal Sim, funcionou!